# android YouTubePlayerView shows "Ad" word

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

We've been using `YouTubePlayerView` with `YouTubePlayer` in our app for some time and recently I noticed we start seeing the word "**Ad**" on the bottom left of the view.

Double checking it I am certain this comes from `YouTubePlayerView` and not from the player or from any other layout part related to our app.

Our initialization of the player is straightforward, we're doing this:

```java
        mYoutubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
        mYoutubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
        mYoutubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
        mYoutubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        mYoutubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackListener);
```

Here's a screenshot so you can see what I mean:

[image: You can see the "Ad" word here]

Any idea how I can get rid of this Ad word ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's such kind a bug of this player. Try this one hack to hide it.
Or change PlayerStyle to CHROMELESS and implement your own controls

```
(((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)((ViewGroup)
        fragment.getView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(5))
        .getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Where fragment is instance of YouTubePlayerFragment

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is the following ;)

```
public void removeFromYoutubePlayer(ViewGroup youtubePlayer, int... depths) {

    for (int i = 0; i < depths.length; i++) {

        youtubePlayer = (ViewGroup) youtubePlayer.getChildAt(depths[i]);

        if (i == depths.length - 1) {
            youtubePlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

}
```

And use this method in the following way

```
ViewGroup youtubePlayer = (ViewGroup) youTubePlayerFragment.getView();

int[] youtubeLogo = new int[] { 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1 }; // remove youtube logo

int[] adWord= new int[] { 0, 0, 5, 0, 1 }; // remove "ad" word

removeFromYoutubePlayer(youtubePlayer, adWord); // removed "ad" word
```