# Does YouTubePlayerView shows ads

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to integrate YouTube videos in my app along with the Ads which are shown while watching the videos on YouTube app.

So I would like to know whether using YouTubePlayerView will solve my problem or do I have to use YouTubeIntents to redirect user to YouTube app in order to preserve the Ads which YouTube adds to the videos

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869218/android-youtubeplayerview-shows-ad-word). It stated that `YouTubePlayerView` shows `Ad` word in the screen. Also, to enable ads, call the [`videoAdvertisingOptions.update`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/videoAdvertisingOptions/update) method. In your request, set the `videoId` parameter to the broadcast `id` that you obtained. Use the `videoAdvertisingOption` resource's [`adFormats[]`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/videoAdvertisingOptions#adFormats[]) property to identify the ad formats (`preroll`, `midroll`, or `postroll`) that you want to enable.